# Why is the graph of a linear relationship curved?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

In light phenomena (lenses and mirrors), we know the formula $\frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$ which describes the relation where,

$v$ = the distance of the image from the mirror
$u$ = the distance of the object from the mirror
$f$ = focal point of curved mirror

Assuming a concave mirror for simplicity, when we plot the $\frac{1}{v}$ on the `x-axis` and $\frac{1}{u}$ values on the `y-axis`, we get a linear curve (i.e a simple straight line).

However, when we plot the ${v}$ `vs.` $u$ graph (i.e $v$ and $u$ on `y and x-axis` respectively) why do we get a curve, when the relationship according to the formula is linear??

> A curve would indicate quadratic relationship, but I can easily prove the the relationship is definitely of power 1. How and why does this happen?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think the relationship between $u$ and $v$ is linear?

Comment: because I can isolate `v + u` alone in the L.H.S, and the relationship is only quadratic for a single case (i.e $v = u$) rest, it's just multiplication of variables which is clearly of the power 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{f}$ for $y$,
we have
$\displaystyle y=-\frac{fx}{\left(f-x\right)}$.

But that expression for $y$ is not a straight line:
since one cannot find constants $B$ and $C$ that

 will make $y=Bx+C$

agree with $\displaystyle y=-\frac{fx}{\left(f-x\right)}$ for all $(x,y)$,

as seen using https://www.desmos.com/calculator ,

[image: desmos-plot]

In fact, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{f}$
and $\displaystyle y=-\frac{fx}{\left(f-x\right)}$
describe a hyperbola,

which can be seen if we rewrite the relation as
$$\left(x-f\right)\left(y-f\right)=f^{2},$$
which is akin to Newton's formula.

[Copy the above equations in Desmos, then enter this one: $\left(x-f\right)\left(y-f\right)=f^{2}$.]

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between $u$ and $v$ is not linear. A linear relationship would be something like $au+bv=c \ {\rm for} \ a,b,c\in\mathcal R$. But $\displaystyle \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$ is not a linear relationship for $v,u$.

However, a linear relationship **is** obtained between $1/v$ and $1/u$, but not between $u$ and $v$.